# springBoot ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory what if downstream is down?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm a bit puzzled with `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and `setErrorHandler(org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler)`

Could you give me some advice please?

I have to pass Kafka message to external system. Right now `ErrorHandler` is rather naive. It sends message to `dead-letter-queue` if message handler throws exception. Message handler could throw exception due to two reasons:

- business checks violation
- external system is unavailable

It's ok to send message to dead-letter-queue if business checks raise exception.

It's wrong to send message to dead-letter queue if external system is unavailable. I have to implement some sort of backoff and retry to consume and handle event until external system comes back alive.

I would like to see if there is some Spring receipt for such case.
Thanks!

Comment: if you are using apache-camel with kafka, then it would be much easier to implement

Comment: could you give any pointers please?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-kafka, https://www.javainuse.com/camel/camel-kafka-example

Answer (score 0):

With the [recent new release (2.3)](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/02/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-3-is-now-available) you can specify a back off for retrying deliveries; you can also configure which exceptions are retryable.

> - The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` can be configured to treat certain exceptions as fatal, disabling retry; you can also now add a `BackOff` between redelivery attempts for failed deliveries.

Note that 2.3 requires Spring Boot 2.2; which is currently available as a [release candidate](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/03/spring-boot-2-2-0-rc1-has-been-released) and will be released soon.